# How to get scrollview to work on 600x1024 screen?

Tags: android, scrollview, screen-resolution, kindle

My app is aimed at small-screen mobile phones and for initial release, I just want to upscale the graphics for higher resolution screens. This works fine until I tried any Android device set to 600x1024, which includes the Galaxy Tab and Kindle targets.

The imageview is scaled to fill the screen and the button underneath isn't drawn. This only happens with 600x1024 screens, in emulation and in Eclipses's UI editor.

Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearViewCredits"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/instructions1_ground"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/instructionsImage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/instructions1" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/instructionsButton"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/sgbutton"
                        android:onClick="backToMenu"
                        android:padding="0dp"
                        android:tag="8"
                        android:text="@string/button_instructions1"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your LinearLayout containing the ImageView and Button is set to wrap_content so the height will be determined by the physical size of the image as you have set the scale type to fitXY.  Are you trying to achieve full screen with the image scaled up?

Comment: Yes. I want the image stretched to fill the screen width and maintain aspect.